# Are all floated elements display:block?

Tags: css

Are all elements that are `{float:left;}` or `{float: right}` converted to `display:block`?

Or is it possible for a floated element to have any other `display` value?

Comment: any element that is floated becomes a `block` element by default.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, an inline element with a `float` will indeed be implicitly converted to block. [Here's some documentation for that over on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/).